# What are the ages of my three daughters?

Tags: logical-deduction

A famous mathematician enters a bus and sit near a lady. The lady says to the mathematician, "If you are famous mathematician, then give me the answer to my question."

**Mathematician**: Yes, of course, please ask.

**Lady**: What is the age of my three daughters?

**Mathematician**: I am confused, please give me a clue.

**Lady**: A multiplication of their ages is 36.

The mathematician thinks and says, "I am confused, please give me some more  clues."

**Lady**: The addition of age is your bus seat number.

The mathematician thinks and says, "I am confused, please give me some more  clues."

**Lady**: This is my last clue, my youngest daughters eye color is brown.

And mathematician give the answer and prove he is famous mathematician.

**So what is the age of the three daughters?**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This question has already been asked.

Comment: Can we have a link to the answer then please?

Comment: the answer is 4,3,3 or 9,2,2
because 36 = 36*1*1 = 18*2*1 = 12*3*1 = 9*4*1 = 9*2*2 = 6*6*1 = 6*3*2 = 4*3*3
and as per clue `my youngest daughters eye color is brown` that means youngest daughter is not one as per grammer the sentence is Plural,therefore possibility of answer is 4,3,3 or 9,2,2